# php URL - replace question mark and parameter with slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

So the orginal url looked like

```
website.com/post.php?id=130
```

using the following htaccess rules i was able to remove .php from the url

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

now the url looks like this

```
 website.com/post?id=130
```

Now i wish to replace the "?id=" with a slash to make the url look like

```
website.com/post/130
```

any tips on what to do here ?

Comment: try this `http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/`

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional rule for that:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/proj1/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/proj1/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: You sure this works ? because its not working for me

Comment: What URL you tried to test and what error did you get?

Comment: website.com/post/title-130

Comment: 500 internal sever error. an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Exact same rule works fine for me on my Apache server. Do you have other rules, not shown in question? Also I suggest to check Apache error.log for 500 error

Comment: no other rules that i know of. if its help, i am on Xampp. i see this error in error.log: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: still no luck here, restarted apache but nothing

Comment: no apache error now, but i am getting 404 , object not found

Comment: That can only happen if your .htaccess and `post.php` are not directly under site root

Comment: About 2 hours back when I asked what URL you tried to test and you responded with `website.com/post/title-130`. Why is `proj1` missing from that URL?

Comment: because this is in localhost. so i go to localhost/proj1/post/title-130.
while when uploaded to the server, its going directly under the root so it will be website.com/post/title-130

Comment: But you're testing it on localhost so test URL should have shown `proj1/` Not providing important information leads to delay in reaching a working answer.

Comment: i thought the answer will be dynamic, that it will work whereever the files are located

Comment: That is not how .htaccess works which is **per directory directive** and certainly not if correct information is not provided upfront.

Comment: You have some config issue as exact same rules posted here are working for me when placed in `proj1/.htaccess`. I used `localhost/proj1/post/title-130` and it loaded `localhost/proj1/post.php?id=title-130` Does `localhost/proj1/post.php?id=title-130` work for you?