# Restructure php url with slashes using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i already asked for help for the same problem same weeks ago but didnt really got a working solution, so i am doing another try to fix it.

So i have a url look like

```
website.com/proj1/post.php?id=130
```

but i want to restructure the url to look like

```
 website.com/proj1/post/130
```

And after discussion, a guy suggested to use following htaccess rules

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/proj1/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/proj1/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

He said that it worked in his environment, but i didnt manage to get work on xampp or my real server ?

can you confirm that the code works ? and do you have any idea why it might not work for me?

Just for the record, i have have placed the htaccess files in the folder "proj1", so it not under the root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php URL - replace question mark and parameter with slash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439512/php-url-replace-question-mark-and-parameter-with-slash)

Answer (score 0):

Your rewriteRule doesnt look right as you are using wrong backrefrences and RewriteConds. You can use the following rule in proj1/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^post/([^/.]+)/?$ /proj1/post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You are the man it worked, but one minor problem is that every link in page are now link to post/images/icon.png, meaning if images was fetched from webiste.com/porj1/images är now modified to webiste.com/porj1/post/images. is there any way to eliminate this side effect

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed path prefix of `/proj1/post`, it's enough to capture the number and use that number in the substitution

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^post/(.+)$ /proj1/post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If both post and the number are variable, you must capture each part separately

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+)$ /proj1/$1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: The .htaccess is in /proj1 not in root.

Comment: @starkeen Thank you, I missed that